# Res.send in wrong directory

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm exploring Node website with some templating engine, Jade.
But, some of my page error at allocating resource.

My folder hierarchy

```
base-project
| public
| | css
| | | style.css
| view
| | dynamic.jade
| | landing.jade
```

While `router.get('/landing')` linking resource to the right path: `base-url/css/style.js`, `router.get('/user/dynamic')` linking resource to wrong path: `base-url/user/css/style.js`.

I've used `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` in my root `app.js`.

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Did you try changing your templates' markup to use either an absolute path or a relative path like `../css/style.css`?

Comment: It fix when I'm using 1 nested directory, like `/user/dynamic`. But, it still break when using `/user/somestring/dynamic`, as the resource linking to `/user/somestring/dynamic`.